# While creating a react component library using webpack got below errors

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-component

[image: 1]

**Below is the console error output.**

```
myLibrary.js:36 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at 915 (myLibrary.js:36:283)
    at r (myLibrary.js:36:409)
    at 565 (myLibrary.js:2:37306)
    at r (myLibrary.js:36:409)
    at 560 (myLibrary.js:21:147)
    at r (myLibrary.js:36:409)
    at myLibrary.js:36:927
    at myLibrary.js:36:944
    at myLibrary.js:36:950
    at myLibrary.js:2:195
915 @ myLibrary.js:36
r @ myLibrary.js:36
565 @ myLibrary.js:2
r @ myLibrary.js:36
560 @ myLibrary.js:21
r @ myLibrary.js:36
(anonymous) @ myLibrary.js:36
(anonymous) @ myLibrary.js:36
(anonymous) @ myLibrary.js:36
(anonymous) @ myLibrary.js:2
(anonymous) @ myLibrary.js:2
Inline Babel script:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: myLibrary is not defined
    at <anonymous>:9:39
    at _Re (babel.min.js:16:1554990)
    at n (babel.min.js:16:1555240)
    at ORe (babel.min.js:16:1555991)
    at babel.min.js:16:1558571
    at XRe (babel.min.js:16:1558581)
    at zRe (babel.min.js:16:1558177)
```

Here is my code. I am trying to build react component library and want to use it in Javascript.

I am using webpack 5 and react js version 18. Can you suggest how can I build the react component using webpack.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
  output: {
    filename: "myLibrary.js",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    library: "myLibrary",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".ts", ".tsx"],
  },

  externals: {
    react: "commonjs-module React",
    "react-dom": "commonjs-module ReactDOM",
  },
};
```